# Got "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header" using the JasperFillManager.fillReport method

Tags: java, jasper-reports

**In my project, i am using jasper report, i have write code to launch jasper report by JButton "Print customer" , but there is lots of errors, The errors is**

> Errors

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file : res\customer.jrxml
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:131)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:103)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:307)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:772)
    at view.CustomerReposrt$2.mouseClicked(CustomerReposrt.java:63)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:278)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4557)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C3F786D
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:966)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:405)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:58)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:126)
    ... 35 more
```

> Jasper Report code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.16.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.16.0-48579d909b7943b64690c65c71e07e0b80981928  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="customer" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="dcd25edb-27be-46bd-aea7-8bb63a227644">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Customer Adapter "/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select * from customer]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="name"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="name"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="customer"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="address"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="address"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="customer"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="name1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Column" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="216" y="20" width="151" height="41" uuid="c26299f7-0288-4284-83fd-a68b6fd60c33"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Andalus" size="20" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer Test]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="220" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="0b82e110-dabd-43fe-b43b-9fd52e97b839">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="eab7558a-fdc0-4ae6-9673-8156f36eeed0"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="438" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="e03c8d1e-b9b1-49cd-81a6-76dcefeab68e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cedacd22-bfc0-414b-aaf0-5fec63b4b4e2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-10" y="40" width="585" height="7" uuid="dd22e933-1ea2-4cd7-9730-61daaf0dcad9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="8bd6e1b0-5f10-4b95-990b-0ee685ec2481"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{name1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="2c43145d-534c-4a94-af83-627a1a2f52bd">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="eab7558a-fdc0-4ae6-9673-8156f36eeed0"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="438" y="18" width="100" height="30" uuid="3e7b8e0c-ce9c-40c8-b94d-868d34fe4e28">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cedacd22-bfc0-414b-aaf0-5fec63b4b4e2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

> Java Class Where JButton

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import org.apache.commons.collections.map.HashedMap;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
import util.MysqlHelper;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomerReposrt extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CustomerReposrt frame = new CustomerReposrt();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public CustomerReposrt() {
        setTitle("Customer report");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 610, 484);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Print customer");
        btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                String report="res\\customer.jrxml";
                
                Map map=new HashedMap();                
            try {
                JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, map,MysqlHelper.openDb());
                

                
                JasperViewer jv=new JasperViewer(jp,false);
                jv.setVisible(true);
            
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JRException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(220, 27, 201, 36);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    }
}
```

> This is my Dadabase connection Class

```
package util;

import java.sql.*;

public class MysqlHelper {

    private static String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/customerdb";

    private static java.sql.Connection connection=null;
    
    public static Connection openDb() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        
        
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return connection;
    }

    
    
    public static void closeDb() {
        if (connection!=null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> Main Code for LAUNCHING REPORT

```
String report="res\\customer.jrxml";
                
                Map map=new HashedMap();                
            try {
                JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, map,MysqlHelper.openDb());
                

                
                JasperViewer jv=new JasperViewer(jp,false);
                jv.setVisible(true);
            
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JRException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
```

> ***Also I have uploded the project on github, [Click here](https://github.com/sainivinit/JasperReportErrors)****

Comment: how you call the jasper is irrelevant, whether it is from Swing or another framework, this is a Jasper issue.

Comment: This question is about the same error (though the code differs a bit). Look at how he builds his paths. There's also no need to pass an empty HashedMap, null should do just fine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56731529/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-3c3f786d-while-trying

Comment: This 'Error loading object from file : res\customer.jrxml' hints that there's something wrong with that file, or either the link to it.

Comment: This is quote from javadoc for method you are trying to use: `@param sourceFileName source file containing the compiled report design`. You can always perform a debug or at least view the documentation or even source code. [JasperFillManager](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.java)